# Name for a new "ad" entry encompassing buyer requests and supplier offers

Tags: single-word-requests

I am developing an application which allows companies to post entries with precise details of what they want to buy and suppliers to submit their offers. Each entry contains information about each item to be ordered, including quantity. What do you call such an "entry"? Is *ad* a suitable word here?

Imagine someone who wants to add a new entry. They will be looking for a button, **New ???**. I'm looking for a word I could replace ??? with.

Comment: Our local paper calls them "Wanted Ads".

Comment: @Urbycoz, if you put that in an answer, it's got my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Such an entry is a **request for bid**. This is a standard term used by purchasing and contracting departments. For example, if I want to provide services to a local governmental agency, I will look at its list of "requests for bids." A request for bid has all the information you describe. I, then, submit a bid.

Another possibility, though less common where I live, is **solicitation**.

Answer (score 0):

In some markets *enquiry* is used for exactly that kind of document.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in your case a possible word could be "*record*", firstly because you told that each entry contains information about each item to be ordered (including quantity) and secondly because probably you were referring to data which have been saved in a DB.
You could also take in consideration the words "note", "listing", "memo" if you like them most.

Comment: Well, "record" is a very generic term. Basically, everything is a record about something. I'm looking for a more specific word.

Comment: I have proposed "record" because in the context of a particular database and of the entry of a row into a table, a "record" is specifically a technical term which is widely used.

Comment: One of the suggestions here is **listing**. That seems like a good choice. It makes intuitive sense to users of the application, who want to enter a new item (the button will show **listing**). It is sensible contextually too, to describe number of entries in the app database, offers per listing, and so forth. Kind of analogous to real-estate listings, but no chance of being confused. Annarita's answer seems quite good.

Answer (score 0):

"Invitation to tender" would be the normal UK term. A google on that led to a wikipedia list of similar terms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_for_bids

Answer (score 0):

It's a little inelegant, but you could try *new buy/sell offer*.

Answer (score 0):

A word/phrase that would describe "precise details of what they want to buy" could be a purchase request.

In code:
PurchaseRequest request = new PurchaseRequest("iPhone4s", 500, 300);

Answer (score 0):

*Request* might be a good term.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen these referred to as "Classified Ads", or "Classifieds" for short.